# FileAppender opens FileHandle but never logs

Tags: java, logging, log4j

In my current project I need to make a certain task create its own logfile separate from what is configured in log4j.properties.

I try to achieve this by attaching a dynamically created FileAppender to the rootLogger:

```
public static void setupAnalysisLogfile(String filename) {
  PatternLayout layout 
           = new PatternLayout("%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p %C{1} %x - %m%n");
  if(Config.CREATE_SEPERATE_LOG)
  {
     FileAppender appender;
     try {
       String path = (Config.LOGFILE_PATH!=null)?Config.LOGFILE_PATH:filename;
       appender = new FileAppender(layout,path);
       appender.setName("Analysis Appender");
       org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("my.package.hierarchy").addAppender(appender);
     } catch (IOException e) {
       org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Config.class).warn(
                                                      "Failed to create a dedicated log "
                                                      + filename, 
                                                      e);
     }
   }        
}
```

When `Config.LOGFILE_PATH` is not null (comes from a commandline parameter) everything works. The logfile is created in the specified path.

However, when `LOGFILE_PATH is null` no logfile is created, or rather *nothing is ever written to it*.

Running the program with `-Dlog4j.debug` gives:

```
log4j: setFile called: /home/tbender/.something/bytecode/OMFG_3527961e3fb1134e1d3221c000879a90ff1022b6/bytecode/OMFG-1340994475441.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
```

When I step through the code and keep an eye on the list of open filehandles, I can see that the filehandle is created during the creation of the appender. Once the application finishes no logfile exists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: So far I could not get eclipse to recognize the attached log4j code. But that is the option I am currently working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay in the end it was not FileAppend that caused to problem but a totally unrelated piece of code that deleted and recreated the folder where my logfile was residing. D'OH!

Good tip for trouble like this: When you are in linux use strace:

```
strace -tt -f -e trace=create,open,close,unlink -o strace.out java -jar yourjar.jar
```

That will show you what files were created, oepened, closed or removed. You can also include a bunch of other stuff. More calls can be found [here](http://bluemaster.iu.hio.no/edu/dark/lin-asm/syscalls.html)